# Prototype-style of JQuery element observer

Tags: prototypejs

I need to replace old event listener code with a new, but without deleting old:

```
onchange="func1();func2();"
```

need to be replace by:

```
onchange="newFunc();func1();func2();"
```

Adding new code to element's onChange event via JQuery was simple:

```
var element = $('element');
var _onchange = element.onchange;
element.onchange = function() {
        //some additional code
        if (typeof(_onchange) == 'function') {
            _onchange();
        }
};
```

Now I need to rewrite it using Prototype.. I suppose it will be like:

```
element.observe('change', function() {

    // new code here
    // then old onChange

}.bindAsEventListener(element)));
```

How can I grab existing onChange's code?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to `.bindAsEventListener()` except in rare cases

so adding the event observing to an element

```
$('element').observe('change',function(){
    //onchange code
});
```

If you do this - it will add the new code as an observer without deleting any other observers setup for that element and event